# TableView displayed the same data two or more times when i get back?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uitableview, xml-parsing

My xml file data reloaded on tableView when i get back from second tableViewController to first and first viewController to second tableViewController. First time data from tableViewController not arise, it shows two times the same xml file data. Why? I am using local xml file in my project.

// In first viewControl

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
        self.eastIndiaArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.westInadiaArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.southIndiaArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.northIndiaArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
- (IBAction)onTapParseData:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSString *xmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"india" ofType:@"xml"];

    self.xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:xmlFilePath]];

    self.xmlParser.delegate = self;

    BOOL success = [self.xmlParser parse];

    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"Parse success");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Parse not success");
    }

    StatesTableViewController *stvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"STVC"];

    stvc.eastIndiaArr1 = self.eastIndiaArr;
    stvc.westIndiaArr1 = self.westInadiaArr;
    stvc.northIndiaArr1 = self.northIndiaArr;
    stvc.southIndiaArr1 = self.southIndiaArr;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:stvc animated:YES];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                           [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    if (trimmedString.length > 0) {

        if ([self.zoneNodeElement isEqualToString:@"eastIndia"]) {
            [self.eastIndiaArr addObject:string];
        } else if ([self.zoneNodeElement isEqualToString:@"westIndia"]) {
            [self.westInadiaArr addObject:string];
        } else if ([self.zoneNodeElement isEqualToString:@"northIndia"]) {
            [self.northIndiaArr addObject:string];
        } else if ([self.zoneNodeElement isEqualToString:@"southIndia"]) {
            [self.southIndiaArr addObject:string];
        }

    }
}
```

//In tableViewControl

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.eastIndiaArr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.westIndiaArr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.northIndiaArr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else if (indexPath.section == 3) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.southIndiaArr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: with out this `[self.tableView reloadData];` try once

Comment: Already i tried this one but it's display same data second time also...

Comment: what the output you expect

Comment: i want to print the data single time only in tableView when i come back one more time also....

Comment: ok in your page how many times you called this `NSString *xmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"india" ofType:@"xml"];
`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I am expecting something wrong in arrays, can u check once bro.....

Comment: ok try once in prakit shah answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137104/discussion-between-vadlani-marking-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like

```
- (IBAction)onTapParseData:(UIButton *)sender { 
// before call the request remove the previous value in your array
[self.eastIndiaArr removeAllObjects]; 
[self.westInadiaArr removeAllObjects]; 
[self.northIndiaArr removeAllObjects]; 
[self.southIndiaArr removeAllObjects];
NSString *xmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"india" ofType:@"xml"]; 

self.xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:xmlFilePath]]; 

self.xmlParser.delegate = self; 

[self.xmlParser parse];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because every time new objects are added in the same old Array.Try removing old objects of your array.(Wherever needed in your code)

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                           [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    if (trimmedString.length > 0) {

        // remove the old object
        [self.eastIndiaArr removeAllObjects];
        [self.westInadiaArr removeAllObjects];
        [self.northIndiaArr removeAllObjects];
        [self.southIndiaArr removeAllObjects];

        if ([self.zoneNodeElement isEqualToString:@"eastIndia"]) {
            [self.eastIndiaArr addObject:string];
        } else if ([self.zoneNodeElement isEqualToString:@"westIndia"]) {
            [self.westInadiaArr addObject:string];
        } else if ([self.zoneNodeElement isEqualToString:@"northIndia"]) {
            [self.northIndiaArr addObject:string];
        } else if ([self.zoneNodeElement isEqualToString:@"southIndia"]) {
            [self.southIndiaArr addObject:string];
        }

    }

    // reload the tableview
 [self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

Comment: try reloading the table view again.

Comment: @PratikShah - it is the delegate i`foundCharacters` its calling each and every time , so remove the data in before webservice call, its not a JSON, it is a XML